# WebView Audio Player stopping after some time automatically

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, media-player

One of the activity in my Android app contains a `WebView` that displays the Audio Player but issue is audio player pausing/stopping after 2-3 min.

Below is my app code and screenshot -

[image]

```
WebView webView = root.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

if (!b1) {
    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String URL1 = "http://xyz.in/webplayer.html";
    webView.loadUrl(URL1);
}
```